# what is giving the error sites/default/modules does not exist

Tags: configuration, error-page

I have a configuration problem somewhere.  My logs give a lot of this: File does not exist: /var/www/drupal-7.34/sites/default/modules.  The site has modules located in /var/www/drupal-7.34/sites/all/modules.  I'm getting the error in apache logs when I try to configure the 'Organization Address and Contact Info' page.  On saving that page I get a dump that starts:
backTrace

```
#0 /var/www/drupal-7.34/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(182): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace()
#1 [internal function](): CRM_Core_Error::handle(Object(PEAR_Error))
#2 /var/www/drupal-7.34/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(931): call_user_func((Array:2), Object(PEAR_Error))
#3 /var/www/drupal-7.34/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(566): PEAR_Error->PEAR_Error("php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resol...", 0, 16, (Array:2), NULL)
#4 /var/www/drupal-7.34/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/Net/Socket.php(156): PEAR->raiseError("php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resol...", 0)
#5 /var/www/drupal-7.34/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTTP/Request.php(737): Net_Socket->connect("maps.googleapis.com", 80, NULL, NULL, NULL)
```

Comment: Do you have a static IP address, and is your DNS hard-coded? Or are you using DHCP instead?

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few other possibilities than Xavier's, which seem on point but not yet solving issue:

1. Check the entries in Administer > System Settings > Directories to see if the sites/default/modules directory appears anywhere and adjust as appropriate if it does.
2. Using phpMyAdmin or equivalent, check in the Drupal database in the registry table filename field for a module with a path at sites/default/modules. If you find one, change it to sites/all/modules after ensuring it is there.

Answer (score 0):

The errors don't seem to be about site/defaults/modules, but about connections problems

Are you sure your server can initiate connections to the internet?

You might have a firewall that prevents it to connect to the google map api (for geocoding) and/or to talk to a dns

If you want to remove this specific error, you can disable the geocoding, but probably worthwhile checking what is the connection issue, civi expects your server to be able to connect to the internet at several places (eg check for updates, read your bounce email, geocoding...)

Comment: from the shell i can access the Internet for CentOS updates fine.  From the gui I can use Firefox to access Webpages (www.civicrm.org) fine

Comment: i have the CiviCRM email configured and sending a test email works fine

Comment: from the shell can you curl maps.googleapis.com ?

Comment: yes, that curl command works.  i checked dns on the server and it is addressable

Comment: when saving the Org address and contact page the dump backtrace shows this at the bottom:  php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution

Comment: Somehow, your webserver doesn't seem to talk to the dns the same way you do from the shell. It might be your network configuration has changed and apache (or whatever you are using) kept an old version of the dns. restart your server, see if it fixes. Anyway, doesn't seem to be civi related, it's a general problem of your configuration most probably

Comment: I found a dns config problem with the server.  fixed that reverse lookup problem, but I am still getting the same error.  seems to be tied to the drupal install as it is not getting status updates.  so may not be a civicrm issue but a drupal one